# aarch64 cross compile linker cannot find a library

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, raspberry-pi, compilation

Can someone give me a hint why the linker did not find a library which exists in `/usr/local/lib`.
I try to cross compile an proprietary sw for a rasberrypi(aarch64) on Windows WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04).
So I use [this tutorial](https://github.com/abhiTronix/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers/wiki/Cross-Compiler-CMake-Usage-Guide-with-rsynced-Raspberry-Pi-64-bit-OS#cross-compiler-cmake-usage-guide-with-rsynced-raspberry-pi-64-bit-os).
My toolchain file is:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE)

# Name of C compiler.
# /opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/bin
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++")

# Where to look for the target environment.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/aarch64-linux-gnu)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH /opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/aarch64-linux-gnu/include)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH  /opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib /usr/local/lib)
set(CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH  /opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin)

# Adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment only.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search headers and libraries in the target environment only.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Compiling works fine but when linking I got the error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target mytest_demo
[ 25%] Linking C executable mytest_demo
/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lmytest_lib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Variable [CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html) denotes paths where **CMake** search libraries via `find_library`. This variable doesn't affect the **linker**. BTW, `/usr/local/lib` usually contains libraries for your **host** system. In your case it is probably x86_64. Placing into this directory libraries for the **target** system (aarch64 in your case) is a bad idea. Instead, place your library into the target system (`/opt/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-64/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib`).